# DRF - return 404 via get_queryset or raise serializer error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am adding a custom action to a ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework which allows users to cancel a particular booking.

There are several criteria for whether a booking *can* be cancelled or not - for example, it needs to not already be cancelled.

Is there a "correct" way of dealing with this situation?

Should I:-

a) filter out the bookings that have already been cancelled in the get_queryset() method so that the API returns an HTTP 404 for an already-cancelled booking

or

b) use a different serializer for cancelling bookings and raise a ValidationError (and therefore an HTTP 400) in the validation if the booking has already been cancelled

or

c) something else entirely

?